# How do I get only the person with the top TotalsS for only one team?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I created two views to get a few results and then made them into one select to use on the inner join. I'm sure there's an easier way to do this. I couldn't think of anything else at the moment.  Please teach me!

```
create view VWSeasonsTBL 
as
    select playerID, count(YearID)totalyears, TeamID 
    from Managers as mgrSeasons
    group by playerID, yearID, teamID
```

```
create view VWSeasonTotal 
as
    select playerID, teamID, sum(totalyears) totalSeasons 
    from VWSeasonsTBL
    group by playerID, teamID
```

```
select 
    players.nameFirst, players.nameLast, teamID, 
    topMgr.totalS 
from 
    (select playerID, teamID, Max(totalSeasons) totals 
     from VWSeasonTotal as topMgr
     group by playerID, teamID) topMgr
inner join 
    players on topMgr.playerID = players.playerIDpk
order by 
    teamID
```

My results

[image: My results]

What I'm looking for

[image: What I'm looking for]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the views. What is the purpose of each view you have defined ?

Comment: The first view I made to count the number of years each manager ID was with for each team. The second view sums the total years with each team as a total. The third view takes the manager ID and assigns a first and last name with the team and total years with them.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't assign a TBL to teamID. When I do assign a TBL I get an error saying " The multi-part identifier "player.teamID" could not be bound."  Only the player table holds the team ID. I was thinking of joining the player and manager tables to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way: It might give you many players per team if it happens that the max poinst per team has been reached by many players on the team

```
select players.nameFirst,players.nameLast, teamID, topMgr.totalS 
from 
(select  teamID,  Max(totalSeasons) totals from VWSeasonTotal as topMgr
group by teamID) topMgr
inner join VWSeasonTotal on topMgr.teamID = VWSeasonTotal.teamID  
and teamID.totals = VWSeasonTotal.totalSeasons
inner join players on VWSeasonTotal.playerID = players.playerIDpk
order by teamID
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a shot. I believe my teamID is causing the problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MAX`, consider a rank of players within each team using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on *totalS* and then in outer query chose the first. By the way, consider [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)s instead of separate views for one SQL statement:

```
WITH CTESeasonsTBL as
   (select playerID, yearID, teamID, count(YearID) AS totalyears
    from Managers as mgrSeasons
    group by playerID, yearID, teamID),

 CTESeasonTotal as
   (select playerID, teamID, sum(totalyears) AS totalSeasons 
    from CTESeasonsTBL
    group by playerID, teamID),

 CTESeasonTotalRank as
   (select playerID, teamID, totalSeasons,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teamID 
                             ORDER BY totalSeasons DESC) AS rank
    from CTESeasonTotal)

select p.nameFirst, p.nameLast, p.teamID, t.totalS 
from players p 
inner join CTESeasonTotalRank t 
   on t.playerID = p.playerID
   and t.teamID and p.teamID
where t.rank = 1
order by p.teamID
```